# RN Firebase Pod Install modifies Lock Dependency With Quotes "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"

Tags: version-control, cocoapods, xcode10, react-native-firebase

When I pod install I am getting one dependency which has quotes around it. I don't want these quotes, and also want to know what they are. The issue is on my team others run this command and do not get the quotes around

"GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"

I am leaving this question somewhat open ended so that people can fill in as much information as possible about what in react native firebase versioning and cocoapods in general is causing this behavior. Thanks ahead of time for all of the thoughtful responses.

```
PODS:
  - Crashlytics (3.9.3):
    - Fabric (~> 1.7.2)
  - Fabric (1.7.11)
  - Firebase/Core (4.8.2):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.0.9)
    - FirebaseCore (= 4.0.14)
  - Firebase/Messaging (4.8.2):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebaseMessaging (= 2.0.8)
  - Firebase/RemoteConfig (4.8.2):
    - Firebase/Core
    - FirebaseRemoteConfig (= 2.1.1)
  - FirebaseABTesting (1.0.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.9):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseCore (4.0.14):
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
  - FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.8):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
  - FirebaseMessaging (2.0.8):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (~> 2.1)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - FirebaseRemoteConfig (2.1.1):
    - FirebaseABTesting (~> 1.0)
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.1.3)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (2.1.3):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.3)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.1.3)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.3)
  - Heap (5.0.5)
```

Comment: Likely related to the plus character in the subspec name.

Answer (score 0):

The `Podfile.lock` file escapes certain characters so that it can be valid YAML. Detailed discussion in this [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7834).